# How to join an OFTC IRC channel using Element?

Tags: irc, chat

I want to join a channel on the OFTC IRC network and I used Hexchat for it. However, the UI was really bad and I wanted something more modern like Slack/Discord. Then I found Element which we can apparently use as an IRC client and it has a more modern interface.

However, even after registering on Element and joining the channel in the Element app, the messages I send are not received by the people on the channel. I verified this using my old Hexchat client where I could not see the messages sent from Element on the channel.

I have another registered user on the same channel and I’m able to dm that user from Element but I’m unable to post in the channel.

Can someone suggest some documentation to follow? Or some step I may have missed?

Comment: Are the messages encrypted?

Comment: No, I haven’t enabled E2E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I found Element which we can apparently use as an IRC client and it has a more modern interface.

No, Element is not an IRC client at all – it is a *Matrix* client, and you can only use it to access IRC through bridges that translate between IRC and Matrix. (When you access OFTC through it, Element thinks it's actually joining a Matrix channel.)

But the two protocols are so different under the hood that many things get lost in translation; for example, if the IRC channel only allows registered users to speak, this isn't even shown on the Matrix side – and while a native IRC client would at least get "Unable to send" error messages in response, the Matrix-IRC bridge is unable to translate them.

Most likely your problem is that the IRC channel requires an account to speak as well. Bridges have no special privileges on IRC and cannot transparently integrate with IRC's (OFTC's) own account system – even though you have an account on the Matrix side, the "fake client" that the bridge connects to IRC on your behalf *isn't* automatically marked as authenticated; the IRC channel still treats it as a guest.

You will need to tell the bridge to authenticate to OFTC's NickServ on your behalf, likely using the `!storepass` command ([see bridge documentation](https://matrix-org.github.io/matrix-appservice-irc/latest/usage.html)) or by messaging NickServ through the bridge (which might be `@_oftc_NickServ:matrix.org` according to [an OFTC-using project's website](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Matrix_and_IRC)).

I would instead recommend TheLounge, IRCCloud, or KiwiIRC if you're looking for a similar UX to the web-based chat systems of today.

Comment: Thanks, I actually learnt this today when I asked on the Matrix forum.